# Will older Adobe Applications (CS5/CS6) work with Mojave?

Tags: adobe, compatibility, mojave

I have some Adobe applications that I use for occasional work (Photoshop, Illustrator, Lightroom, Acrobat).  These are the versions *prior* to the CC version (Creative Cloud) and they work on El Capitan through High Sierra.

I don't do enough graphics work justify the cost of a monthly CC license and these older version have been more than enough for what I want to do.

Now, with the new Metal framework of Mojave, will the Adobe Apps continue to function?  Contacting Adobe results in a support call that (magically) turns into a sales call for CC.

Has anyone tested Adobe CS5 or 6 products on Mojave beta as of yet and if so, what were the results?

Answer (score 10):

**Depends on App**

I have tested the following application with basic functionality and ability to open. Tell me if you need me to test others.

**Note:** I am on Retina computer so it's not going to look great no matter what software I'm using. Also, with almost every app (including Apple Apps) there are error messages about 32-Bit support ending soon or portions of apps are too old to be used but I have found they mostly have no effect on anything.

**My Config**

- MacBookPro 2017
- 3.5 Ghz Intel Core i7
- 16GB Memory
- macOS Mojave Beta 7

### **Works**

- Adobe Photoshop CS6 - Bit slow but not too noticeable
- Adobe Illustrator CS6
- Adobe Bridge CS6 - Didn't test import but should work
- Adobe Premiere Pro CS6
- Adobe After Effects CS6
- Adobe Acrobat X Pro

**Does Not Work**

Distiller :(

**If anyone can add to this please do!**

Comment: Checking Lightroom and Acrobat now

Comment: Awesome work... I would love for this to become a canonical answer for future questions (inevitable) questions about Adobe CS compatibility with Mojave.

Comment: @Allan Thanks and sounds good! Please know I only tested basic functionality.

Comment: @Allan Also Adobe Audition is broken on Mojave. It opens and you can edit everything but it won't play. No sound and it doesn't move.

Comment: Lightroom seems to open and load catalog files fine, although I receive the message that "applications associated with Lightroom are unoptimized for your Mac and will need to be updated [in the future to 64 bit architecture]"

Comment: Is that LR 4, 5, or 6?

Comment: You could add this info to the crowd-sourced database at [RoaringApps](https://roaringapps.com/apps?platform=osx) too. Would be useful. Mojave is pretty much all question marks at the moment.

Comment: JBis, may you try InDesign CS6? It is one of the apps with the older code.

Comment: @PaoloT Cant get to install

Comment: I'm probably alone in this one... but what about Fireworks CS6 ?  I'm slowly transitioning that work out to Illustrator and others but still have a ton of source materials that were generated from that way back when that I'd like to still be able to access.

Comment: @Jbis perhaps this should be Community Wiki as several people can add info

Answer (score 4):

My config:iMac 27in 4.2 GHz 48 GB ram running Mojave 10.14

Photoshop CS6 functions, but won't save. Error message: photo is open in another app (which it is not). Also, app display is not resizable top to bottom (but is, side to side). Weird. Everything worked well until more recent Mojave betas. No problem with InDesign CS6 or Acrobat Pro.

Comment: No save is not a universal issue. On Mojave 10.14.4 even on a fairly stacked Mac Pro (lots of peripherals, lots of installed software with kexts like Keyboard Maestro) Photoshop 13.0.6 x64 opening, adding layers and saving does not generate any issues for me. This is not a deep test but if the situation changes, I'll update my comment.

Answer (score 0):

CS5.1 Photoshop v12.1 64bit crashes if you touch the top bar of a file, or try to select the swatch and layers etc., you can navigate using the menus okay and do some things, but try to select the gradient tool and it crashes too...
CS5.1 Illustrator v39 32bit seems to run fine at the moment, although you get a pop up from Apple saying the developer needs to update it —LoL.  Haven't really tested out the rest of the CS suite as don't really use them these days.
Have just downloaded Pixelmator to replace Photoshop at ¥3,600/$30
This is on a MacAir6,2 (mid 2013) with i7 and 8GB ram.

Comment: Just following up to this, the article at https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/kb/photoshop-and-macosmojave.html  gives some advice on settings.  I tried this and the crashes stopped....

Answer (score 0):

As of July 2019 (Mojave 10.14.5), CS6 suite works for me. This includes Distiller, mentioned in another answer as unworking. I can confirm that Bridge CS6 works (though I also seem to be able to get Bridge CC free with a non-subscription Adobe ID account.)

Dreamweaver CS6 works, but is sluggish for me.

However, these apps are EOL and will not work in Catalina. Even the 64-bit ones rely on 32-bit support processes for licensing, updates, etc.

There are a range of alternatives to Adobe's products, that can compete in function and price.

Answer (score -4):

my two cents for Catalina.
I can confirm Adobe PS6 works.

(even with some tricks..)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/272897)

Comment: I simply added a tip, as I usually do in stackoverflow. If someone falls here, can anyway have useful infos