# Can macOS Mojave run 64-bit version of Adobe CS6?

Tags: mojave, adobe

I have ordered a new 27" iMac with macOS Mojave. I use 64-bit version of Adobe CS6.

Will macOS Mojave run it?

Comment: Mojave still supports 64 bit apps, so I don't believe that qualifier is relevant.

Note this is probably the last version in which they will work, despite being 64 bit. I tested booting with the -no32exec boot arg, and CS6 wouldn't launch. :(

Answer (score 0):

As noted in [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/328409/279727) answer, you should be able to run Adobe CS6 in macOS Mojave 10.14.

Another user shared their experience [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/MacOS/comments/9pshmu/adobe_cs6_any_issues_on_mojave/e84bhw3) and was able to use CS6 fine.