# CS6 Illustrator on Mac OSX 10.15 Catalina - anyone managed to run it?

Tags: macos, adobe, catalina, 64-bit

I was browsing Internet for some hints, but did not find anything yet. And the communication is a bit missleading, one say it won't work, becuase of 32-bit references, another claim it should work, because CS6 Illustrator itself is 64-bit.

Ended up after install with:

[image]

and after clicking the icon:

> “Adobe Illustrator CS6” needs to be updated.

[image]

according to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adobe_Illustrator

> Adobe Mercury Performance System, **64-bit memory support**, new user
>   interface, gradient on a stroke, pattern creator tool, ImageTrace
>   (replaces Live Trace)

From the OSX system information:

```
Adobe Illustrator CS6:

  Version:  682
  Obtained from:    Identified Developer
  Last Modified:    19/08/2019, 14:06
  Signed by:    Developer ID Application: Adobe Systems, Inc., Developer ID Certification Authority, Apple Root CA
  Location: /Applications/Adobe Illustrator CS6/Adobe Illustrator.app
  Kind: 64-bit
  Get Info String:  16.0.0, Copyright © 1987-2012 Adobe Systems Inc.  All rights reserved.
```

**so it is 64bit**

Comment: I do recall reading somewhere that Adobe CS6 apps were not going to be compatible with MacOS Catalina, although I don't recall if that referred to all CS6 apps or just some of them. If I can track down the source I'll let you know.

Comment: Maybe obvious and far from ideal, but three options might be: 1. Don't upgrade, 2. setup a small second boot partition for an earlier System with CS6, 3. use a VM.

Comment: https://appuals.com/how-to-install-legacy-java-se-6-runtime-on-macos/

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/328406/will-older-adobe-applications-cs5-cs6-work-with-mojave/

Comment: [Photoshop CS6 is a 64-bit executable…but a bunch of associated helper apps are 32-bit.

Has anyone actually tried to run Photoshop CS6 on Catalina? Does it even launch successfully? If so, is it usable?](https://twitter.com/siracusa/status/1182281280316203010)

Answer (score 6):

I was able to get Photoshop CS6 to work with the following. Might work for Illustrator.

**package contents > contents > MacOS and launch the executable**

(to find the package contents, find the file "Adobe Photoshop CS6.app" in the Apps folder, right-click and select "Show Package Content")

Comment: Note, this is only going to work if the app in question is a 64-bit version. If it's not, then it won't work.

Answer (score 4):

Here's how I got it working:

1. Move `/Applications/Adobe Illustrator CS6/Plug-ins/Illustrator Formats/IdeaFileFormat.aip` out of the `Plug-ins` folder.
2. Rename `/Library/Application Support/Adobe/APE` to `APE - disabled`.
3. Right-click `/Applications/Adobe Illustrator CS6/Adobe Illustrator CS6.app` and select `Show Package Contents`.
4. Make an alias of `Contents/MacOS/Adobe Illustrator` and move it to `/Applications`.
5. Double-click the alias.

This is pretty crash-prone, and the Dock icon isn't fully functional, but I've used it a few times to update files and it gets the job done.

If I had a Creative Cloud license like the OP, I'd just use the current versions. But I don't use Illustrator or other Adobe software often enough to justify the high subscription price (especially considering many bugs still don't get fixed even with this forced maintenance fee).

Comment: looks good! Thanks for input! A lot of people will find it yousefull.

Comment: sorry your solution does not seem to be usable any more ;(

Comment: `2019-10-27 14:46:51 : ERROR RegisterForEventsRequest, VCException occured : connect(/tmp/com.adobe.csi.ctrl-CS6-andi) failed <2: No such file or directory>`

Comment: @adlomedia, still got error
segmentation fault

Comment: It was working inconsistently for me, so I switched to Affinity Designer. That handles slices much better than Illustrator, and can export to multiple resolutions automatically, so now I wish I'd switched years ago.

Answer (score 1):

It won't work anymore. Once you update to Catalina. They need to update the app to 64-bit, so we can download it again and install it on our device.

Comment: this. 32 bit software won't work on Catalina, period.

Comment: The core CS6 apps are all 64 bit, it's just ancillary stuff that is 32 bit.

Answer (score 1):

No, I did *not* manage to run Illustrator CS6 in macOS 10.15 Catalina, even if CS6 is 64-bit. I have some related advice, though (hope it fits in here).

I have an Enterprise license allowing me to install the newest versions of most Adobe software. So I uninstalled Illustrator CS6, then I ran the Creative Cloud app for installing the last version (Illustrator 23.1.1). However, it crashes after 5% of the installation process with this error message:

```
FATAL: Error (Code = 151) executing in command 'CreateMacAliasCommand' for package: 'AdobeColorCommonSetRGB_1_0-mul', version:1.1.4
FATAL: Error occurred in install of package (Name: AdobeColorCommonSetRGB_1_0-mul Version: 1.1.4). Error code: '151'
WARN: Unable to delete file at "/Library/ColorSync/Profiles/Recommended".
```

So apparently it has some issues with installing ColorSync profiles. Adobe is not able to help with this issue so far. Their main advice is to downgrade to macOS 10.14 Mojave.

However, since I ran into this issue, I tried to do it in a different way on my other Mac: I updated from Illustrator CS6 to the latest version (23.1.1) *before* upgrading to macOS 10.15 Catalina. This worked fine, so on that computer I can run Illustrator without issues.

So for those who plan to upgrade to Catalina *and* have the ability to update to a newer version of Illustrator, my advice is to update Illustrator *first*.

Comment: don't post a different question as an answer. Post a question instead.

Comment: can you get CC for free when having license on CS6?

Comment: @jwenting, I did not post any questions.
andilabs: No, I do not think so.

Comment: The system volume is read-only in MacOS Catalina. Maybe the installer cannot delete any files from /Library due to that? If so that could explain the problem. Personally I am not a fan of OS's that break users' existing software, nor do I like subscription-based software, so I'm stuck using older versions of the OS. For "security" I simply leave my machine disconnected from the internet. Personally I would suggest that you simply stop using Photoshop and find an alternative that does not expect you to pay for lack of ownership.

Answer (score 0):

I have Adobe CS6 running under a virtual machine running Mac OSX El Capitan under Parallels under Catalina.  Works great.

Basically, you buy and install Parallels into your Catalina system, then set up an older version of Mac OS X as a virtual machine, then install Adobe CS6 into that virtual machine (making sure you have previously de-activated any previous versions of CS6, and that you have an install file/disk, valid Adobe Account, and CS6 serial number).  Parallels is a $100 program that allows you to run other OS under Mac OS X.  You can find install disks for older versions of Mac OS X on the web, or at the present time you can get an install file for Mojave from Apple for free.  Don't allow the Apple Store to upgrade your old Mac OS X to Catalina!

Comment: If you're buying VM software specifically to run *macOS* guests, I *highly* recommend VMWare Fusion over Parallels. I've used both, and VMWare is very well ahead for Mac guests (even if I think Parallels had a slight edge for Windows guests).